# Kubernetes multiple stateful sets pods communication

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, statefulset

Within same stateful set afaik you can interact between particular pods just by referencing it directly, like this - `pod-{0..N-1}.my_service.my_namespace.svc.cluster.local`.
(some more info here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id).

However in my case I have 2 different stateful sets, and I want to be able `statefullset1-pod-0` from 1st stateful set to interact with `statefullset2-pod-0` from 2nd stateful set(and also `statefullset1-pod-1` with `statefullset2-pod-1`, and so on). Is it possible? If yes, can you please provide example configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However in my case I have 2 different stateful sets, and I want to be able statefullset1-pod-0 from 1st stateful set to interact with statefullset2-pod-0 from 2nd stateful set(and also statefullset1-pod-1 with statefullset2-pod-1, and so on). Is it possible? If yes, can you please provide example configuration?

Yes, your apps can access other `StatefulSet` as it access any other Service in the cluster, use the DNS name of the Service. E.g. if you have created Service `statefullset2-pod-0` in the same namespace, you can access it with `http://statefullset2-pod-0` if it is a http-service.

Remember, for StatefulSet, you are responsilbe to create the Pod-identity services yourself.

From the [StatefulSet documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/):

> StatefulSets currently require a Headless Service to be responsible for the network identity of the Pods. You are responsible for creating this Service.